# named 9.7.3 takes lots of CPU on Centos

Tags: central-processing-unit, bind

My named is taking ~60% CPU on both cores (2 instances of named).
It is resolving ~12 domains per minute and has ~20 cached requests per domain within 5 minutes.
The named cache size is 400MB.

Is there anything else I forgot to do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have been hit by the leap second bug.

Run `date -s "$(date -u)"` from the commandline and see if that helps.